# Usage of RTP packets in Android Streaming application

Tags: android, video, streaming, rtsp

Updating my previous question...

Currently I am working on a live media streaming application. I have been able to use the Media Recorder class to record medias and store it in a file. Currently I am trying to stream this media from android to Adobe Media streamer using RTP. What I have done us using the parcel file descriptor I have packaged the video contents which are captured from the device camera. Now I would want to use the RTPPackets class provided by Sipdroid to convert this packets into RTP packets. 
I am having problems integrating this RTP Packets and using the same in to my application as I see there are multiple steps to be done
1) Creating RTP packets, even though I have got the code for RTP packetizer I am not exactly sure how to use the same and where to use this. Because I clearly not sure on what would be the default payload value, ssrc and ccrc values. May the first time these will carry the default values but the second time onward what would set the values for these parameters would it be the parcel file descriptor?
2) Creating a simple server kind of code on the mobile which continues to create the RTP packets and keep sending them to the Adobe media server?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
K.Saravanan.

Comment: Finally I was able to connect to Flash media server using the red5 code and stream a file... Hurray... but now comes the biggest problem of converting the input streams captured from the Video camera into flv... :( ... The video captured from the Android camera isnt streamed to the Flash Media server using the same Desktop application. So not sure on where to go from here... Any help would be appreciated...